# Matlab coding repetition help required

Tags: matlab

So I have this code,

```
clc
clear all
close all

a = [1,2];
b = [1,1];

r = sqrt((a(:,1) + b(:,1))^2+((a(:,2) + b(:,2))^2));

finished=false;
while ~finished
    %default case, finish if case is done
    finished=true;
    if r<5
        display('reaching target')

        a = a+1;
        b = b+1;

        %start from begin in this case:
        finished=false;

    elseif r>5
        disp('job done') 
    end
end
```

Now what I want is the code to take initial values of `a` and `b`, calculate `r`, and if `r<5` display reaching target and start all over again from top after increasing value of each component of `a` and `b` by 1. Repeat the thing again, now again if the value of `r` is less than 5 start again after increment of values. If the value of `r>5` display `'job done'` and stop running the code.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is, I've made a guess and posted an answer. If my answer is not what you're looking for, please update the question to indicate what the desired behavior is, and how the current behavior is different from desired.

Comment: @Praetorian, one of the undesired features of the code posted above is that it never terminates. Other than that I agree with you, the question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking how you can avoid repeating the formula for calculating `r` within the loop. You could use an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) to do this.

```
calc_r = @(x, y) sqrt((x(:,1) + y(:,1))^2 + ((x(:,2) + y(:,2))^2));
```

Then call this function to update `r` whenever needed

```
r = calc_r(a, b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to recalculate `r` every time you update `a` and `b`, like this:

```
a = [1,2];
b = [1,1];

r = sqrt((a(:,1) + b(:,1))^2+((a(:,2) + b(:,2))^2));

finished=false;
while ~finished
    %default case, finish if case is done
    finished=true;
    r = sqrt((a(:,1) + b(:,1))^2+((a(:,2) + b(:,2))^2));
    if r<5
        display('reaching target')

        a = a+1;
        b = b+1;

        %start from begin in this case:
        finished=false;

    elseif r>5
        disp('job done') 
    end
end
```

## A few side notes:

Your vectors are 1-dimensional, meaning you don't need the `:`, so a simpler way to write it would be:

```
r = sqrt((a(1) + b(1))^2+((a(2) + b(2))^2));
```

You don't really need `if` and `elseif` to determine when to stop, you can use it directly as a input in `while`. I would probably have done something like this (assuming you don't want to change your approach drastically using anonymous functions etc.).

```
a = [1,2];
b = [1,1];

while sqrt((a(1) + b(1))^2 + (a(2) + b(2))^2) < 5
    a = a + 1;
    b = b + 1;

    disp('reaching target')
end
disp('job done')
```

If your equations are a bit more complex than the one above, you would probably want to calculated it separately as you did initially (to make the code readable). I would still advice you to drop the `if`s and `else`s nonetheless.